# Spring Boot Embedded Undertow Server : java.io.IOException: UT000128: Remote peer closed connection before all data could be read

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, undertow

A web application which uses spring boot 2.2.3.RELEASE and Undertow 2.0.29.Final as embedded server having the issue `java.io.IOException: UT000128: Remote peer closed connection before all data could be read`. And this is the only configuration setting I have used in the application.properties file which is related to Undertow.
`server.undertow.max-parameters = 5000`
The complete error log is given below,

```
2020-01-23 09:22:09.804 ERROR 2136 --- [ XNIO-1 task-27] io.undertow.request                      : UT005022: Exception generating error page /error

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: UT000128: Remote peer closed connection before all data could be read
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:523) ~[jakarta.servlet-api-4.0.3.jar!/:4.0.3]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590) ~[jakarta.servlet-api-4.0.3.jar!/:4.0.3]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:152) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:251) [undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchToPath(ServletInitialHandler.java:186) [undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.error(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:501) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.error(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:427) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:308) [undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78) [undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133) [undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48) [undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43) [undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249) [undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78) [undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99) [undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376) [undertow-core-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830) [undertow-core-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_231]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_231]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_231]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: UT000128: Remote peer closed connection before all data could be read
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.parseFormData(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:841) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.getParameter(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:714) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameter(ServletRequestWrapper.java:150) ~[jakarta.servlet-api-4.0.3.jar!/:4.0.3]
        at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameter(ServletRequestWrapper.java:150) ~[jakarta.servlet-api-4.0.3.jar!/:4.0.3]
        at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameter(ServletRequestWrapper.java:150) ~[jakarta.servlet-api-4.0.3.jar!/:4.0.3]
        at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:123) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) ~[undertow-core-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60) ~[undertow-core-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269) [undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: UT000128: Remote peer closed connection before all data could be read
        at io.undertow.conduits.FixedLengthStreamSourceConduit.exitRead(FixedLengthStreamSourceConduit.java:338) ~[undertow-core-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.conduits.FixedLengthStreamSourceConduit.read(FixedLengthStreamSourceConduit.java:255) ~[undertow-core-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSourceChannel.read(ConduitStreamSourceChannel.java:127) ~[xnio-api-3.3.8.Final.jar!/:3.3.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSourceChannel.read(DetachableStreamSourceChannel.java:209) ~[undertow-core-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$ReadDispatchChannel.read(HttpServerExchange.java:2343) ~[undertow-core-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.form.FormEncodedDataDefinition$FormEncodedDataParser.doParse(FormEncodedDataDefinition.java:136) ~[undertow-core-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.form.FormEncodedDataDefinition$FormEncodedDataParser.parseBlocking(FormEncodedDataDefinition.java:294) ~[undertow-core-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.parseFormData(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:835) ~[undertow-servlet-2.0.29.Final.jar!/:2.0.29.Final]
        ... 63 common frames omitted
```

Does it have anything to do with timeout?
`server.undertow.always-set-keep-alive` is `true` by default. I do not see this issue in my localhost, but this issue keep on appearing in different HTTP request URL in production.

Comment: This is a problem at the client. It sent a content-length but didn't send that much data, and closed the connection instead of waiting to receive the response,

Comment: @ user207421 If so how can we resolve the issue in the server side? or its just a benign exception and just ignore?

Comment: @user207421 my production is in EC2 AWS and also supported by Load balancer, is it because of the load balancer? Because I am still having the issue and can not find a solution.

Comment: Hello @SebinThomas, i am experienced the same issue with spring boot,  have you found the solution for this problem? thank you

Comment: @DionSaputra I could not find a solution. The client (Web Browser or Mobile App and etc.,)  closed the connection before the response. That's what I think.